# Monacaのプロジェクト自体のアイコンの変更方法について

Tags: monaca

タイトルのままの質問ですがMonacaにて、プロジェクト自体のアイコンの変更方法がわかりません。

Monacaにログインして、ダッシュボードの「すべてのプロジェクト」の
各プロジェクト名の左側の部分の画像です。

どこから設定すれば宜しいでしょうか？

ご教授宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 編集レビューキューに質問者と同名の別アカウントがいますが…

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトから、
config→iOS App Setting→Icon
にて、アップロードしたら変更されました。

おそらくAndroidやWindowsでもICONをアップロードして更新すると差し替わります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 iOSのアイコンの設定画面より画像をアップロードしましたら反映されました。
(何度か試しましたがAndroidのアイコン設定画面より画像アップロードしても、なぜかダメでした。) また、プロジェクトの更新ボタンでは画像は反映されず、
一度ログアウトして、再度ログインしなければ反映されませんでした。 ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ネコ鼠 自己解決された場合には、ご自身で解決方法を回答として記載し、その回答を承認して頂ければ、他の方が本質問が解決済みであることがよくわかります。よろしくお願いします。